# What is GraphQL query to determine if GitHub package exists within an Organization?

Tags: github, graphql, github-graphql, github-package-registry

How do I query GitHub Packages to determine whether a package already exists?  I want to prevent CI/CD from attempting to publish a Maven package if that package already exists.

I'm trying a query that looks like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: bearer <some token>" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.packages-preview+json" -d <my query> https://api.github.com/graphql
```

where `<my query>` looks like:

```
query {
  organization(login: "myorg") {
    registryPackagesForQuery(packageType: MAVEN, first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
            name
            id
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting my packages returned:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "registryPackagesForQuery": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "com.example.myorg",
              "id": "<some id>"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, there is a `query` argument (of type `String`) for `registryPackagesForQuery`, but I don't know how that query format should look.  Any attempt to add in a value seems to result in no data being returned.

What is the correct format of the query, and how does this query vary if I want to check whether a specific version of a package exists?

The base Query docs are here: https://developer.github.com/v4/query/.

Organization: https://developer.github.com/v4/object/organization/

RegistryPackageConnection: https://developer.github.com/v4/object/registrypackageconnection

RegistryPackage: https://developer.github.com/v4/object/registrypackage/

Comment: did you find an answer to this? looking for the exact same

Comment: Yes,the actual test of whether a particular package exists just comes down to a HEAD call to the POM file associated with that package. I built it into a Gradle plugin that I can't share (yet), but the call is to https://maven.pkg.github.com followed by "/ORG/REPO/GROUP_DELIMITED_WITH_SLASHES/ARTIFACT_ID/VERSION/ARTIFACT_ID-VERSION.pom" (needed to split the URL as SO autoformats it and it breaks the rendering).

Answer (score 0):

This may be off-topic, but wouldn't it be simpler to use a maven plugin for that? Like https://github.com/chonton/exists-maven-plugin maybe ?